# Updating Combobox bound to an observable collection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I'm binding observablecColletion in ViewModel to a combobox in View (using MVVM Caliburn.Micro). The obsevableColletion is getting its items from a string array which gets the file names in a directory. So my question is: How can i make the combobox to update automatially when i add or delete a file in the directory?

Here is my code:
ViewModel

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _combodata;
Public ObservableCollection<string> ComboData
{
    get
   {
      string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Documents");
      _combodata = new ObservableCollection<string>(files);
      return _combodata;
   }
   set
   {
       _combodata = value;
       NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ComboData);
   }
}
```

View:

```
<ComboBox x:name = "ComboData" ......../>
```

Comment: Whenever item gets added in directory, you have to add it to ObservableCollection ComboData as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a view model that does what you want. It uses a [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.aspx) to detect changes in the file system. It uses [Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx) to marshal the [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.aspx) events back to the UI thread (you don't want to change an [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) on background threads). You should call [Dispose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx) of this view model when you are done with it.

```
public class ViewModel : IDisposable
{
    // Constructor.
    public ViewModel()
    {
        // capture dispatcher for current thread (model should be created on UI thread)
        _dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;

        // start watching file system
        _watcher = new FileSystemWatcher("C:\\Documents");
        _watcher.Created += Watcher_Created;
        _watcher.Deleted += Watcher_Deleted;
        _watcher.Renamed += Watcher_Renamed;
        _watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        // initialize combo data
        _comboData = new ObservableCollection<string>(Directory.GetFiles(_watcher.Path));
        ComboData = new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<string>(_comboData);
    }

    // Disposal
    public void Dispose()
    {
        // dispose of the watcher
        _watcher.Dispose();
    }

    // the dispatcher is used to marshal events to the UI thread
    private readonly Dispatcher _dispatcher;

    // the watcher is used to track file system changes
    private readonly FileSystemWatcher _watcher;

    // the backing field for the ComboData property
    private readonly ObservableCollection<string> _comboData;

    // the ComboData property should be bound to the UI
    public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<string> ComboData { get; private set; }

    // called on a background thread when a file/directory is created
    private void Watcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        _dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => _comboData.Add(e.FullPath)));
    }

    // called on a background thread when a file/directory is deleted
    private void Watcher_Deleted(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        _dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => _comboData.Remove(e.FullPath)));
    }

    // called on a background thread when a file/directory is renamed
    private void Watcher_Renamed(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        _dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                _comboData.Remove(e.OldFullPath);
                _comboData.Add(e.FullPath);
            }));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've to bind an event to listen to changes in the directory you're adding/removing stuff 
from. Just setup `FileSystemWatcher` and add/remove stuff from your observable collection as it alerts you.

Example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx